# Tkinter: adding existing content to a frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a simple text based game in python/tkinter, and made a basic setup so far. It displays the intro. text, and then you can type(this is still a work in progress). However, I realized that there is going to be a lot of text, and thought of the frame's scrollbar capability.

However, I added my current content to a frame and the functions don't work now. I was following someone's example, so I don't know if it's right. Here is the code:

```
from Tkinter import *

w=Tk()
w.configure(background="navy")
w.iconbitmap(default="blankIcon.ico")
w.title("Decimated world")
w.resizable(0,0)

introText="When you wake, you see that the sky is dark; you can't tell the time of day."

scen1="You head toward the Town hall."

class App(Frame):
def __init__(self,w):
    Frame.__init__(self,w)
def key(event):
    print event.char

t=Text(w)
t.insert(INSERT,introText)
t.configure(state=DISABLED,background="navy",foreground="white")
t.pack()

def do_command(command):
    t.configure(state=NORMAL)
    t.insert(INSERT,'\n>>> {}'.format(command))
    t.configure(state=DISABLED)

s=StringVar()
e=Entry()
e.configure(background="navy",foreground="white")
e.focus_set()
e.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def enter(event):
    do_command(e.get())
    if e.get()=="walk north":
        t.configure(state=NORMAL)
        t.insert(INSERT,"\n"+scen1)
        t.configure(state=DISABLED)

e.bind("<KeyRelease-Return>",enter)


w.mainloop()
```

I'd appreciate anyone's help with putting the existing functions/widgets into a frame. Thanks.

Comment: your indentation is incorrect in your example code. Since python is highly dependent on indentation, we can't know for sure what you intended until you fix the indentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "the functions don't work now"? Could you be more concrete (error message, expected behaviour, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the text has a name you can use the pack and unpack methods.

For Example:

```
b = Label(root, text='Click Me')
b.pack()
```

and then to remove it:

```
b.pack_forget()
```

and then when you want to add it again just type:

```
b.pack()
```

It is as simple as that!